# Exibindo o erro do banco no fetch

Tags: node.js, react-native

Bom dia.
Quero exibir o erro 400 no front(RN) que o back(node) fornece, usando o fetch.

```
function add(){
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/AOTT7C1TT75a8s5RH1TR/${desc._id}/skaoskao`,{
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            user:`${Home.user._id}`,
            "Authorization":`Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        --> console.log(res)
    })
}
```

consigo obter o erro nesse `console.log(res)` que retorna-me `{"error": "Você já pediu esse produto"}` mas eu não entendo como que passo esse error para tela do celular(RN)

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exibir o erro 400, é necessário utilizar o método `catch`, que possui a resolução da promise para o caso de haver um erro ao fazer a requisição.
Um exemplo utilizando o seu código é o seguinte:

```
function add(){
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/AOTT7C1TT75a8s5RH1TR/${desc._id}/skaoskao`,{
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            user:`${Home.user._id}`,
            "Authorization":`Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(function(error) {
       console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
   });
}
```

A informação do seu erro 400 está na variável `error`.

Para mais informações de como u utilizar a api fetch verifique o site do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).